# onYouTubeIframeAPIReady with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube-api

I'm having problems with the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function not being called. i have div for you tube videos
`<div class="panel-body custom-content-part"></div>`

this is jquery code which used

```
     var html   = '<iframe id="ik_player_iframe" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' +
                        videoId +'??enablejsapi=1&version=3" width="100%" height="420"></iframe>';

        $('#content-view .custom-content-part').html(html);                 

        //Holds a reference to the YouTube player
        var ik_player;          
        //this function is called by the API

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          //creates the player object
          ik_player = new YT.Player('ik_player_iframe'); 
          console.log('Video API is loaded');                  
          //subscribe to events
          ik_player.addEventListener("onReady","onYouTubePlayerReady"); 
          ik_player.addEventListener("onStateChange","onYouTubePlayerStateChange");
        }

        function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
          console.log('Video is ready to play');
        }   

        function onYouTubePlayerStateChange(event) {
          console.log('Video state changed');
        }
```

Somehow the method onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is never triggered.

Comment: Same problem here, but ive been using it for a while and without changing anything yesterday stopped working, so i guess its something on the youtube api itself.

Comment: are you using segment IO ?

Comment: No i was not using segmented IO...

Comment: Can you provide a JSfiddle that demonstrates the issue?